# What type of valve spring compressor tool do you use in a 2002 Ford Escape?

Tags: ford, tools, cylinder-head, escape

It'd be awesome if the engine had a name because I know other makes and models use the same engine. Anyhow I know [OEMTOOLS 27040](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004FELIYY) doesn't fit because I tried it already. I was thinking of trying [ARES 15031](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084Z9HD9M) because you can get it for $20 on Amazon but it says it only works for the exhaust valves on 4 valve engines.

I have a Haynes manual but they don't tell you what tool to use. I can't find good information on Google. I don't want to waste time and money trying a bunch of different tools. Does anyone know which tool to use? The cheaper the better.

[This tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084HGMQ58) says it will work without having to remove the heads. The heads are off. Is there an easier tool? Haaallllpppppp.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the top of the head?

Comment: Is this the I4 or V6 engine?

Comment: @Handy,. there she is. It's a tight squeeze to say the least. You could say there's not a lot of room.

Comment: @Paulster2 6 cylinders of fury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, but I would have thought that a valve spring compressor that looks like this one should fit -
[image]

I got this from [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OTC-4572-Large-Spring-Compressor/dp/B000F5ECUY)

Comment: Yeah that looks like it would get the job done. I forgot to circle back to this question. I ended up using one of these babies https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B084HGMQ58/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. Now, I guess the one I used is better for if the heads are still on the engine block but believe me it would be a MEGA PITA removing/installing the wedges that hold the springs in place with the heads still on the car. WAYYYYYY to easy to drop them and trust me, you don't want to drop them in the engine. Be REALLL careful or consider taking the heads off to do this job imo.

Comment: btw @HandyHowie, it's back in service. Last problem I had was some engine vibrations which went away (enough) after changing some of the engine mounts. She's gtg. 500,000 miles here we come!

Comment: Good news, well done.

Answer (score 2):

This valve setup looks similar to a 2011 Ford Taurus head I worked on recently. It looks like there's more room in this head for one of those valve spring compression tools you can rent from AutoZone, but if not you can try what I did.

To uninstall the springs, I placed a long socket (can't remember the size, maybe a 15mm) on top of the spring and struck the socket with a mallet. It might take a few tries, but the spring does come out so long as they're not super stiff springs.

To install them back in, I used [this technique](https://youtu.be/VPYSAk-qWXM). Basically, you place a plastic bag over the spring and press down on a socket so that the keepers can fall into the notch in the spring. The plastic bag is there just to kinda keep the keepers in place.